# How to change text size of TextMobject in Manim

Tags: manim

I hope you are all doing great!

I am wondering how to make text smaller in manim.

I know you can do `text.scale(0.8)`, but I want to know how to do it after it has been used.

For example,

```
text.scale(0.8)


self.play(Write(text))

makeSmaller(text) <-- what I'm looking for
```

So far, I've tried `ApplyMethod(text.scale(0.8))` with no success.

Thank you so much

**Edit:**
Ideally, I do not want to create two different `TextMobject`'s and then transition between two animations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is:

```
ApplyMethod(text.scale, 0.8)
```

or

```
self.play(text.scale, 0.8)
```

More info [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnWMwkcZGkM)